# How do I make my website fit all screen sizes?

Tags: html, web, iframe

On my website, I was trying to make the size of an iframe be the same on all resolutions / screen sizes.

A Iframe on my website: [Website](https://spew45.github.io/games/drift-boss.html)
View source of the page: View-source

I tried this code;

```
<p align="center"><iframe src="" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; border: 0px; border-radius: 0px; margin-top: 20px;" id="iframe" class="myIframe"></iframe></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    $('.myIframe').css('height', $(window).height()+'px');
    </script>
```

although it didn't really help me that much as the size didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This code sets the width and height of the iframe to be equal to the size of the viewport when the page loads, and whenever the window is resized.

```
<p align="center">
  <iframe src="" style="border: 0px; border-radius: 0px; margin-top: 20px;" id="iframe" class="myIframe"></iframe>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  const iframe = document.querySelector('.myIframe');

  function setIframeSize() {
    iframe.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
    iframe.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  }

  setIframeSize();

  window.addEventListener('resize', setIframeSize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexbox. Set the body element to be flex and the p tag. Set the p tag to flex 1 and html and body tags to 100% height and width. It will expand to fill the screen space. You also dont need the border div, just set the background color on the text div itself.

```html
<html style="
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
"><head><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.png">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Classes</title>

</head><body style="background-color: #001b2e;display: flex;height: 100%;width: 100%;margin: 0;">



<div class="text">
<embed src="/dump/text.html">
</div><p align="center" style="
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 24px;
"><iframe src="https://mathplayground.com/drift-boss-v3/index.html" id="iframe" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe></p>

</body></html>
```